# struts2 best practice - where do I put helper methods? Static classes OK?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, struts2

I have some repetitive code that is used by a few of my actions in Struts 2.

Needless to say I want to have this code only exist in one place, so I will collect it up into a method and put it ... where?

What is the best practice? Do I create a helper class for each type of helper method? One big helper method? One big static class? A few static classes?

I'm using MVC.

I've read other answers on stackoverflow and none seem to quite answer my question.

Many thanks for your help.

**EDIT update with examples, as requested:**

For instance:

I have a couple of lines of code that adds an arraylist to the session, which stores when a certain object has been 'rated' (for that session). Its called in a few actions across the application.

Also, I have a view component that is included on multiple JSP pages, and needs to be loaded with some data from the model. I would need to copy/paste the code into each action (obviously want to avoid this).

Hope that clarifies. Please let me know if it does not.

Comment: Can you give some examples of what kind of methods you're talking about?

Comment: @Steven Benitez, thanks I've given some examples as you've suggested

Comment: Create a superclass where it makes sense or use static methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My general rule is that if the methods are computational, in other words if they just perform a function (like math), I will create a class with static methods and use it all over the place.

I have a utility package that I include in a lot of my projects as a jar with string manipulation and validation functions for instance because they rarely change.

String validation is a good example. I have a Validation class that I use a lot to check for null or empty strings and return a boolean. I just call it from my action classes like:

```
if(Validation.string(value)){
      // do magic - huzzah
}
```

I try to group utility methods into classes especially if I use then all over the place. It tends to save me from re-typing, searching through classes for a good idea I had whenever, and provides a single instance of the code in case I need to update, modify, overload, or override.

Answer (score 1):

For view components included in multiple JSP pages and objects saved to session, I've created a base action class and sub-action classes to avoid repetitive code.

```
public class BaseAction extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware {
    protected Map session;
    protected ResourceBundle rb;
    // common getters for shared view components and common setters
    ...
}
```

--

```
public class SubAction extends BaseAction {
   ...
```